# Line - Circle intersection test in 3d world?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, geometry, line-intersection

i have a 3d world where i have several 2d circles laying on the ground facing to the sky.

how can i check if a line will intersect one of those circles frop top-to-down?

i tried to search but all i get is this kind of intersection test:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html

but its not what i need, here is image what i mean:
http://imageshack.us/m/192/8343/linecircleintersect.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in a coordinate system, where the ground is given by z = c for c some constant, then you could simply calculate the x, y coordinates of the line for z = c. Now for a circle of origin x0, y0 and radius R, you would simply check if

(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 <= R^2.

If this is true, the line intersects the circle.

Comment: where did you define the vector of my 3d line? im not trying to check just one point inside a circle

Comment: The intersection between the line and the circle will be a single point. If that point is within the circle, the line intersects.

Comment: i dont understand this but i will try... i just wonder why you dont define z at all there

Comment: ok this cant work because theres nothing telling me what is x/y, is it the start of my line, or the end of my line? edit: oh nvm you said its the intersection of the plane, so now i need two codes, first intersect a plane and then a circle... is this really the fastest way? i only have triangle plane intersection code in my use so it would get super slow...

Comment: z is the z-coordinate in your coordinate system. Assuming z = 0 is the ground, then you would plug in z = 0 in the equation of your line, obtain x, y and check whether the circle includes x, y.

Comment: i dont understand at all what youre up to., is there some fast way to check interesction point on a plane on specific z-pos in 3d system with a 3d line? then i guess i could use your function and calculate it in bare 2d and using a point check inside circle.

Answer (score 4):

In a 3D sense you are first concerned with not with a circle but with the plane where the circle lies on. Then you can find the point of intersection between the ray (line) and the plane (disk).

I like to use homogeneous coordinates for point, planes and lines and I hope you are familiar with vector dot `·` and cross products `×`. Here is the method:

Plane (disk) is defined by a point vector `r=[rx,ry,rz]` and a normal direction vector `n=[nx,ny,nz]`. Together they form a plane `W=[W1,W2]=[n,-r·n]`.

Line (ray) is defined by two point vectors `r_A=[rAx,rAy,rAz]` and `r_B=[rBx,rBy,rBz]`. Together they form the line `L=[L1,L2]=[r_B-r_A, r_A×r_B]`

The intersecting Point is defined by `P=[P1,P2]=[L1×W1-W2*L2, -L2·W1]`, or expanded out as

```
P=[ (r_B-r_A)×n-(r·n)*(r_A×r_B), -(r_A×r_B)·n ]
```

The coordinates for the point are found by `r_P = P1/P2` where `P1` has three elements and `P2` is scalar.

Once you have the coordinates you check the distance with the center of the circle by `d=sqrt((r_p-r)·(r_p-r))` and checking `d<=R` where `R` is the radius of the circle. Note the difference in notation between a scalar multiplication `*` and a dot product `·`

If you know for sure that the circles lie on the ground (`r=[0,0,0]`) and face up (`n=[0,0,1]`) then you can make a lot of simplifications to the above general case.

[ref: [Plucker Coordinates](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Introduction_To_Plcker_Coordinates.shtml)]

**Update:**

When using the ground (with +Z up) as the plane (where circles lie), then use `r=[rx,ry,0]` and `n=[0,0,1]` and the above intersection point simplifies to

```
r_p = [ rBy-rAy, rAx-rBx, 0] / (rAy*rBx-rAx*rBy)
```

of which you can check the distance to the circle center.

Comment: Then look them up at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product **&** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: im not a math guy, i dont understand that stuff

Comment: @Rookie - I suggest you pick up a Physics for Games book, or a basic Vector algebra book to start understanding *that stuff*.

Comment: so... i want to hit a circle with a line and now i must read for 3 years in some school to finally finish this tiny function? i dont have the time to go to schools like that, nor it would be much of a use for myself since i dont need these things all the time... i doubt every programmer knows these things either. not to mention i would probably forget these math things very soon once i "learned" them... as i said, im not a math guy. it just doesnt get in my head.